# Device to device messaging using GCM without registering an app server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible for a device to send message to other devices using Google cloud messaging without an app server at all?

I have a centralized database using Google Cloud Datastore. The app will get required registration ids from the centralized database and the database is updated by all the devices. So, getting registration ids is not a problem.

Can this be done using upstream messaging? I am not sure because i have searched a lot but never saw an example where app server is not used for this purpose.

This question is not duplicate of another question, because here i have central database to store registration ids which is mentioned as a problem in another question.

Comment: What is your definition of 'app server'?

Comment: A server which is hosted by me and it is responsible for sending messages to other devices like shown at Google I/O about GCM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use GCM in Android without a dedicated server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519153/is-there-a-way-to-use-gcm-in-android-without-a-dedicated-server)

Comment: Check http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most basic sense no, not at this time. You cannot send an upstream message from one device to another without an app server. You can create an app server on your device application but that is not recommended. The current recommendation would be to use an app server to facilitate your device to device messages.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out to do exactly the same. There is a lot of complications otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

To answer is it possible? Yes it is.

Sometime back I have created a POC to send GCM message to self, so I know its very much possible. I configured my GCM to work with any ip in developer console i.e. 0.0.0.0.

just use HTTP post to send your message from android as you would have done from Server.

Comment: thanks for the explanation along with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Like (most) everything else, there is an API for that.

Google hosts its GCM service on GCM Connection Servers. [The official document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server) requires you to create an App Server to issue the API requests to the Connection Servers.

Alternatively you could setup the Connection Server to accept requests from any IP around the world, and then issue the requests via your client app. [The API is here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http) and it's quite simple.

### Seurity issues

Bundling your API key with your app, and setting the Connection Server to unrestricted connections is an obvious major security issue.

### Why bother?

Why bother doing all of this? Instead I would use a free service like Parse.com, which takes care of the users database and offers up to 1000000 messages a month free.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your explanation helps a lot. Can you be specific about security issues you mentioned. Is it necessary to bundle the API key with app, can i store it on central database instead. if so, then does it resolves the security issue ?

Comment: The main security issue here is allowing unrestricted connections to your server. Doesn't matter where you store the API key - it can be sniffed from  your network transactions. The 2 issues combined are a major security hole.

Comment: You mentioned ' unrestricted connections to your server ' but there is no server. In this case, every device acts as a server and makes connection with gcm server (ccs) directly to send message to other devices without any intermediate. Does the security issue still exists ?

Comment: Yes. You give unrestricted access to your account on the GCM server.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone actually done this. I would like to see example android project.